# How to remove the file created by X509Certificate2.ctor() under AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\Keys\?

Tags: .net, certificate, x509certificate, x509certificate2

Whenever this is executed:

```
new X509Certificate2(bytes)
```

...a new file is created under `C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\Keys\`

How can I remove this file when I'm done with the cert ?

I tried:

```
using(new X509Certificate2(bytes)) {...}
```

Nope.

```
...
cert.Reset();
...
```

Nope.

Tried writing the bytes to a file and reading from that.

Nope.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't set `X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet` then the file should get deleted when you Dispose (or Reset) the certificate, or when it later gets garbage collected.

If you do set X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet then .NET will no longer automatically delete it and you have to do it manually.

```
try
{
    AsymmetricAlgorithm alg = cert.PrivateKey;

    if (alg is RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCsp)
    {
        rsaCsp.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
        rsaCsp.Dispose();
    }
    else if (alg is DSACryptoServiceProvider dsaCsp)
    {
        dsaCsp.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
        dsaCsp.Dispose();
    }

    return;
}
catch (CryptographicException)
{
    // Maybe not a CAPI key
}

try
{
    CngKey cngKey = null;

    using (RSA rsa = cert.GetRSAPrivateKey())
    using (DSA dsa = cert.GetDSAPrivateKey())
    using (ECDsa ecdsa = cert.GetECDsaPrivateKey())
    {
        if (rsa is RSACng rsaCng)
        {
            cngKey = rsaCng.Key;
        }
        else if (dsa is DSACng dsaCng)
        {
            cngKey = dsaCng.Key;
        }
        else if (ecdsa is ECDsaCng ecdsaCng)
        {
            cngKey = ecdsaCng.Key;
        }
    }

    if (cngKey != null)
    {
        cngKey.Delete();
        cngKey = null;
    }
}
catch (CryptographicException)
{
}
```

If you hadn't set PersistKeySet but your process terminated abnormally, then the notion that the key should have been deleted is forgotten, and a new PFX will create a new file.  Knowing what to delete then is hard, and beyond the scope of this answer.